# Xcode 8 beta quits when reference node added

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, swift3, xcode8

Every time adding a `reference node` to a `.sks file` my **Xcode Version 8.0 beta (8S128d)** quits.
This happens when dragging a `.sks file` into the scene editor as well as when setting a reference in the utilities panel of the scene editor.

Is there a known fix for this yet, or is this happening just to me?

**Problem Details:**

```
Process:               Xcode [13184]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               8.0 (11160.22)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-11160022000000000~6
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [13184]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-07-03 23:28:36.746 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        8DC6473C-B559-3B8F-E89B-804956710C20

Sleep/Wake UUID:       F1951D94-FD7F-4776-9FEB-53E99E5D1EE0

Time Awake Since Boot: 98000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       11000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 8S128d
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException): *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (Field) for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked
UserInfo: {
    "__NSCoderInternalErrorCode" = 4864;
}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   -[NSCoder(Exceptions) __failWithExceptionName:errorCode:format:] (in Foundation)
  4   -[NSCoder(Exceptions) __failWithExceptionName:errorCode:format:] (in Foundation)
  5   _decodeObjectBinary (in Foundation)
  6   _decodeObject (in Foundation)
  7   -[SKSceneEditor sceneEditController:didPerformDragOperation:atLocation:] (in IDESpriteKitParticleEditor)
  8   -[SKSceneEditController inputView:didPerformDragOperation:atLocation:] (in IDESpriteKitParticleEditor)
  9   -[SKInputView _tryAcceptFilenameListDrop:sender:] (in IDESpriteKitParticleEditor)
 10   -[SKInputView performDragOperation:] (in IDESpriteKitParticleEditor)
 11   NSCoreDragReceiveMessageProc (in AppKit)
 12   DoMultipartDropMessage (in HIServices)
 13   DoDropMessage (in HIServices)
 14   SendDropMessage (in HIServices)
 15   DragInApplication (in HIServices)
 16   CoreDragStartDragging (in HIServices)
 17   -[NSCoreDragManager _dragUntilMouseUp:accepted:] (in AppKit)
 18   -[NSCoreDragManager dragImage:fromWindow:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:] (in AppKit)
 19   -[NSWindow(NSDrag) dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:] (in AppKit)
 20   -[NSOutlineView dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:] (in AppKit)
 21   -[NSTableView _doImageDragUsingRowsWithIndexes:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:startRow:] (in AppKit)
 22   -[NSTableView _performClassicDragOfIndexes:hitRow:event:] (in AppKit)
 23   -[NSTableView _performDragFromMouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 24   -[NSTableView mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 25   -[NSOutlineView mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 26   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView mouseDown:] (in IDEKit)
 27   -[NSWindow _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 28   -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 29   -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 30   -[IDEWorkspaceWindow sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 31   -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 32   -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 33   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 34   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 35   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException
```

[…]

```
External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 3
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 69518
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 2960

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=593.7M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=593.7M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.5G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.5G(100%)

                                  VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                          SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                       =======  ======= 
Accelerate.framework                 256K        3 
Activity Tracing                    2048K        2 
CG backing stores                   29.2M        5 
CG image                            24.8M      173 
CG shared images                     368K       12 
CoreAnimation                      105.5M      364 
CoreData Object IDs                 4100K        3 
CoreUI image data                   5824K       44 
CoreUI image file                    444K       12 
Dispatch continuations              16.0M        2 
Foundation                            40K        7 
IOKit                               7940K        2 
Image IO                            1164K       18 
JS JIT generated code              256.0M        5 
JS JIT generated code (reserved)   768.0M        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                      8K        3 
MALLOC                             270.6M      118 
MALLOC guard page                     32K        7 
Memory Tag 242                        12K        2 
Memory Tag 251                        60K        4 
Memory Tag 83                        492K       40 
OpenCL                                32K        5 
Process Corpse Info                 2048K        2 
SQLite page cache                   1024K        8 
STACK GUARD                         56.1M       31 
Stack                               22.3M       33 
VM_ALLOCATE                          116K       17 
WebKit Malloc                       16.6M       48 
__DATA                              61.4M      524 
__IMAGE                              528K        2 
__LINKEDIT                         150.9M      266 
__TEXT                             443.8M      504 
__UNICODE                            552K        2 
mapped file                        263.9M       90 
shared memory                       16.3M       11 
===========                       =======  ======= 
TOTAL                                2.5G     2336 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space       1.7G     2336 

Model: MacBookPro11,2, BootROM MBP112.0138.B17, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.18f15
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.5f3 17904, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
```

Answer (score -1):

This is actually an issue with .Sks files since the Xcode 7.3.1 Beta version. Check out on the Apple developer forum as well.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47511

If you are reporting a bug, report under Graphics & Games> SpriteKit

Hope this helps. Thanks.